# How to insert all rows in a new table that have certain initials (pl/sql)

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

when a row contains the initial(s): 'H' I want to insert all the rows into a new table. How can I accomplish this? 
 This is the cmp_employer_employees table:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by a new table, exactly having the same structure with the surrent one ? And so by a row contains initials? At least one row should have a non-null value for initials ..?

Comment: Yes a table that's exactly the same. And I want to insert the rows where the initials are  the character 'H'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the new table has the same structure as `cmp_employer_employees`, you can add the records where the initials are "H" with an insert like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO new_table
    SELECT *
      FROM cmp_employer_employees
     WHERE initials = 'H';
```